# Calling my function, causes the program to crash - C | 3DS Homebrew

Tags: c, crash, homebrew

I've been writing a homebrew for the Nintendo 3DS, which is written in C. It simply parses a JSON file and prints it onto the screen. The problem is that after parsing and printing it on the screen, it just crashes.

Code:

```
char JSON_FILE[] = "jsbr-ford-mustang.json";
static int jsoneq(const char *json, jsmntok_t *tok, const char *s) {
    if (tok->type == JSMN_STRING && (int) strlen(s) == tok->end - tok->start &&
        strncmp(json + tok->start, s, tok->end - tok->start) == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}

const char * parse_json(char* value) {
    u8* file_buffer; FILE *file = fopen(JSON_FILE,"rb"); if (file == NULL) printf("Error.\n");
    fseek(file,0,SEEK_END); off_t size = ftell(file); fseek(file,0,SEEK_SET); file_buffer=malloc(size);
    if(!file_buffer) printf("Error.\n");
    off_t bytesRead = fread(file_buffer,1,size,file); fclose(file);
    if(size!=bytesRead) printf("Error.\n");
    int i; int r;
    jsmn_parser p; jsmntok_t t[128]; jsmn_init(&p);
    r = jsmn_parse(&p, file_buffer, size, t, sizeof(t)/sizeof(t[0]));

    if (r < 0) {
        printf("Failed to parse JSON: %d\n", r);
        return 1;
    }
    if (r < 1 || t[0].type != JSMN_OBJECT) {
        printf("Object expected\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Debug START\n");
    for (i = 1; i < r; i++) {
        if (jsoneq(file_buffer, &t[i], value) == 0) {
            printf("Debug 1\n");
            break;
        }
        printf("Debug 2\n");
    }
    printf("Debug 3\n");
    return printf("%.*s\n", t[i+1].end-t[i+1].start, file_buffer + t[i+1].start);
}

int main() {
    gfxInitDefault();
    consoleInit(GFX_TOP,NULL);
    printf("P1\n");
    printf("Description: %s",parse_json("description"));
    printf("P2\n");
    printf("Sync spacing: %s",parse_json("synchronization_spacing_us"));
    while (aptMainLoop()) {
        hidScanInput(); u32 kDown = hidKeysDown();
        if(kDown & KEY_START) {
            consoleClear();
            break;
        }
        gfxFlushBuffers();
        gfxSwapBuffers();
    }
    gfxExit();
    return 0;
}
```

Debug output:

```
P1
Debug START
Debug 2
Debug 2
Debug 1
Debug 3
Ford Mustang, 40MHz, No. 23019
```

Here is a video of what happens: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zpt_BEMyIOc

Here is the GitHub repo that I have for it: https://github.com/lavanoid/3DS_JSON_Parser

Comment: Besides adding the diagnostic printfs, have you tried to debug it?

Comment: Yeah, I'm new to C but I've tried various little tweaks but I've had no luck :( I'm not sure what would be the best way to debug it.

Comment: For example, why doesn't the effect of `printf("Description: %s"...)` not appear?  (That should tell you almost exactly where it crashes.)

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. It crashes when it gets to "P2", after successfully returning the value of `printf("Description: %s"...)`.

Comment: So I honestly don't know what causes it to crash :/

Comment: So what should I do to my code, to fix that?

Comment: Oooh. Do you think you could paste some example code? I'm so new to C that I'm not sure about arrays and how to use snprintf in the way that you said.

Comment: a few suggestions:  1) place only one statement per line, to make it easy for us humans to read/understand the code  2) separate code blocks with a blank line  3) indent (say 4 spaces) after every opening brace '{' and un-indent before every closing brace '}'  4) never use tabs for indenting as each wordprocessor/editor has the tab stops/tab widths set differently.

Comment: please, when posting about a runtime problem (the program crashes) post code that cleanly compiles, is 'relatively' small and shows the problem.   Then we can examine the code via a debugger, to help you determine the cause of the crash and what to correct to eliminate the crash.

Comment: suggest reading the man page for each system function that you call (or plan to call) so you know the details and what to expect from each called system function

Comment: Thanks :) I'll be sure to do that, next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) regarding the return value of printf():

> On success, the total number of characters written is returned.
>
> If a writing error occurs, the error indicator (ferror) is set and a negative number is returned.
>
> If a multibyte character encoding error occurs while writing wide characters, errno is set to EILSEQ and a negative number is returned.

you cannot do this: `return printf("%.*s\n", t[i+1].end-t[i+1].start, file_buffer + t[i+1].start);`

because your function needs to return a `const char *`, not an `int`, which is returned from printf().

You should use sprintf() to print the string you want into a buffer (tempString for example)

```
static char *tempString;
...
if(tempstring != NULL) {
    free(tempString);
    tempString = NULL;
}
tempString = (char *)malloc(t[i+1].end-t[i+1].start+1);
if(tempString != NULL) {
    sprintf(tempString,"%s", file_buffer + t[i+1].start);
    return (const char *)tempString;
} else {
    return "malloc error!";
}
```

Comment: of course, tempString must be a pointer to malloc'd memory, otherwise the caller will be referencing the contents of an array on the stack, a stack that is nolonger valid after the sub function exits.

Comment: Thanks for the code example :) I took your code and added it but it still crashes the 3DS back to the home screen. Bummer. Oh well. I must be doing something wrong. I appreciate the response.

Comment: If you're satisfied with the answer feel free to accept it

Comment: I just need to squash that last bug. It prints out the rest of the file, for some reason. Latest code: https://github.com/lavanoid/3DS_JSON_Parser/blob/master/source/main.c